# I have a text file with each line containing an integer. I want to open the text tile and count the number of integers in the file

Tags: c++, oop, file-io

```
void DataHousing::FileOpen() {
    int count = 0;
    // attempt to open the file with read permission
    ifstream inputHandle("NumFile500.txt", ios::in);

    if (inputHandle.is_open() == true) {
        while (!inputHandle.eof()) {
            count++;
        }

        inputHandle.close();
    }

    else {
        cout << "error";
    }

    cout << count;

}
```

This is getting stuck in the while loop.  But shouldn't the while loop end when it gets to the end of file?  Also, I'm not even sure yet if it is counting correctly.

Comment: You never touch the file in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly easy way to do this would be to use `std::cin` instead. Assuming that you want to count the number  of integers in a file you can just use a while loop like so:

```cpp
int readInt;
int count = 0;
while(std::cin >> readInt){
    count++;
}
```

Then you just pass in the file as an argument parameter to your executable as so:

`exec < filename`

If you prefer to go through the route you're going then you can just replace your while loop condition with `!inputHandle.eof() && std::getline(inputHandle, someStringHere)` Then proceed to check if `someStringHere` is an int and increment your count if it is like so:

```cpp
int count = 0;
std::string s;

ifstream inputHandle("NumFile500.txt", ios::in);

if (inputHandle.is_open() == true) {
        while (!inputHandle.eof() && std::getline(inputHandle, s)) {
            if(check to see if it's a number here)
                count++;
        }

        inputHandle.close();
}
```